# How to read value of parent ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` that has an embed in `PageViewController`. The page ViewController of course instantiate `two more viewControllers` that displays content. My problem is that the two instantiated viewControllers need to read a value that is created in the `ParentViewController` and I don't know how can I access this value.

Any Idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To access the root controller you can try:

```
  guard let rootController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? YourRootController else {return}
```

Then you can access the needed value like:

```
 guard let value = rootController.YourValue else {return}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not my case because I'am not using a navigationController, my viewControllers are Embed in one in another and not presented

Comment: Have you tried segue? Passing the needed value upon transitioning from PageViewController to ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are static that you will be passing to the page view controllers just create a variable inside view controller and assign the value to it before presenting the view controller.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
      var yourValue: String = "Something you want to pass"
      .....

      func setupPageViewController() {
           let vc1 = ChildViewController()
           let vc2 = ChildViewController()
           vc1.value = yourValue
           vc2.value = yourValue
           .....
           .....
           pageViewController.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2], direction: .forward, animated: true)
      }
}
```

Or if you want to get notified whenever there is a value change in the parent view controller I would suggest you to use NSNotificationCenter. Refer this link for NSNotificationCenter tutorial.

https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/using-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift-eb70cf0b60fc